# Reduce length of decimal variable (algorithm)

Tags: decimal

I have a string of decimal digits like:

```
965854242113548732659745896523654789653244879653245794444524
length : 60 character
```

I want to send it to a function, but first I want reduce the length of it as much as possible. How can I do that?

I think about convert it to base-34, that will be `1RG7EEWTN7NW60EWIWMASEWWMEOSWC2SS8482WQE`. That is 40 characters in length. Can I reduce it more some way?

Comment: You could send it in completely binary form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number fits into 70 bits - for such a small payload compression seems nonsensical. Assuming that the server API supports arbitrary binary data, I would simply encode the value in binary and prefix it with the number of bytes needed.

- 1 byte length information - for 854657986453156789675, the example you gave initially, this would be 9
- 9 bytes of binary payload

→ 10 bytes of data transferred for your example.

Your example in hex:

```
09 2e 54 c3 1e 81 cf 05 fd ab
```

With the length given in bytes, this of course supports only decimals up to 255 bytes length, but I suppose this is sufficient. If your transport protocol has a built in concept of *length of a packet*, you could even skip the initial length byte.

Important: ensure that all sides use the same endianness. As you are transmitting your data over the network, network byte order ([big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking)) would be natural.

If you want to transmit very large numbers, keep in mind that you can use any compression algorithm you like on the binary representation of your data. However, your payload must be significantly larger in order to make compression feasible - for example, using zLib compression for the above 9 byte payload results in an 18 byte payload due to the overhead for the zLib datastructures.

If (and only if) you cannot use arbitrary bytes for your payload, you can encode your data (possibly after compression). Most modern libraries have built in support for [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), so this would be a natual way of representing the data.

Comment: I just add a sample decimal, my decimal actually is like : 965854242113548732659745896523654789653244879653245794444524 that has 60 character lenght

Comment: @hamze for the new example, you will end up with 26 bytes if you use a length byte: `19 99 de 94 cd 69 f7 bc c0 bd 6f a8 85 3f bd c3 7a d5 71 10 72 86 77 88 e4 ec`